# troubles connecting USB3 drive

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I have two distinct PC with the same issue.

If I connect an external USB3 HDD to the front panel I get a lot of issues. Sometimes it is recognized but I get errors transferring files, other times it is not recognized at all.

Last time I tried dmesg looked like this:

```
[52306.980676] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[52311.990308] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[52312.046207] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52312.570682] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[52312.596010] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52312.697334] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[52312.723848] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52312.881146] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52313.140860] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[52318.150455] usb 4-5: unable to get BOS descriptor set
[52323.144147] usb 4-5: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[52323.144157] usb 4-5: can't read configurations, error -110
[52323.200064] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52323.728556] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[52323.753871] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52323.855183] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[52323.881460] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52324.038995] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52324.302707] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[52329.312284] usb 4-5: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[52329.312295] usb 4-5: can't read configurations, error -110
[52329.368238] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52329.900736] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[52329.926051] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52330.027357] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[52330.053635] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52330.211170] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52330.470883] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[52330.487587] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61b6
[52330.487596] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
[52330.487601] usb 4-5: Product: Samsung M3 Portable
[52330.487605] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[52330.487608] usb 4-5: SerialNumber: 00000000011E3877
[52330.488186] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52330.488344] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52330.488706] scsi7 : usb-storage 4-5:1.0
[52330.488916] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52330.489075] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52331.491780] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  M3 Portable      3    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[52331.493112] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[52331.493372] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953504688 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[52331.493652] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[52331.493663] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[52331.493956] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52331.493965] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52331.495097] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52331.495107] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52331.989039] usb 4-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[52332.005225] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22000
[52332.005227] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22040
[52332.005610] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52332.005769] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52332.132856] usb 4-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[52332.149042] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22000
[52332.149044] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22040
[52332.149425] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52332.149584] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52332.276676] usb 4-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[52337.286185] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[52337.374047] usb 4-5: USB disconnect, device number 15
[52337.381979] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[52337.381981] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[52337.381982] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[52337.381983] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[52337.381984] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[52337.381987] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[52337.381989] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[52337.382031] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[52337.382039] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[52337.382051]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[52337.382229] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[52337.382240] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[52337.382241] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[52337.382242] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[52337.382291] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[52337.382293] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52337.382294] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[52337.382539] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22000
[52337.382542] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22040
[52337.874545] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[52337.899698] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52338.001242] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[52338.027784] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52338.185055] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52338.444768] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[52338.461340] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61b6
[52338.461349] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
[52338.461354] usb 4-5: Product: Samsung M3 Portable
[52338.461358] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[52338.461361] usb 4-5: SerialNumber: 00000000011E3877
[52338.461932] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52338.462089] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52338.462533] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-5:1.0
[52338.462739] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52338.462898] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52339.465490] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  M3 Portable      3    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[52339.465947] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[52339.466121] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953504688 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[52339.466370] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[52339.466372] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[52339.466761] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52339.466764] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52339.467739] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52339.467751] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52340.157069]  sdc: sdc1
[52340.158022] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52340.158025] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52340.158026] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[52340.302496] usb 4-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[52345.312006] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[52345.399882] usb 4-5: USB disconnect, device number 18
[52345.403802] scsi 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[52345.403807] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[52345.403816] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[52345.403818] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[52345.403821] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[52345.403823] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[52345.403824] Read(10): 28 00 74 70 1d 00 00 00 08 00
[52345.403838] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1953504512
[52345.403840] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188064
[52345.403848] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188064
[52345.403874] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188084
[52345.403875] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188084
[52345.403877] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[52345.403878] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[52345.403881] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[52345.403885] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188085
[52345.403908] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[52345.415902] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22800
[52345.415904] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22840
[52345.920395] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[52345.945502] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52346.047036] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[52346.073340] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52346.230852] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52346.490520] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[52351.500177] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[52351.556098] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52352.088558] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[52352.113686] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52352.215215] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[52352.241524] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52352.399026] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52352.658743] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[52352.685209] usb 4-5: unable to get BOS descriptor
[52357.680349] usb 4-5: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[52357.680358] usb 4-5: can't read configurations, error -110
[52357.736261] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52358.268725] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[52358.293854] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52358.395378] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[52358.421692] usb 4-5: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[52358.579189] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[52358.838906] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[52358.855513] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61b6
[52358.855521] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
[52358.855526] usb 4-5: Product: Samsung M3 Portable
[52358.855530] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[52358.855534] usb 4-5: SerialNumber: 00000000011E3877
[52358.856125] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52358.856283] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52358.856703] scsi9 : usb-storage 4-5:1.0
[52358.856917] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[52358.857075] usb 4-5: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[52359.859832] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  M3 Portable      3    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[52359.861297] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[52359.861480] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953504688 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[52359.861755] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[52359.861762] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[52359.862021] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52359.862027] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52359.863097] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52359.863107] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52360.255973]  sdc: sdc1
[52360.256976] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[52360.256979] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[52360.256981] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[52360.401006] usb 4-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[52360.424127] usb 4-5: device firmware changed
[52360.424154] usb 4-5: USB disconnect, device number 29
[52360.424814] scsi 9:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[52360.424816] scsi 9:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[52360.424824] scsi 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[52360.424826] scsi 9:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[52360.424827] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[52360.424829] scsi 9:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[52360.424830] Read(10): 28 00 74 70 1d 00 00 00 08 00
[52360.424834] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1953504512
[52360.424835] quiet_error: 128 callbacks suppressed
[52360.424837] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188064
[52360.424843] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188064
[52360.424854] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188084
[52360.424856] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188084
[52360.424859] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[52360.424860] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[52360.424863] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[52360.424866] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 244188085
[52360.424889] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[52360.424891] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[52360.441058] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22c80
[52360.441064] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88039ef22cc0
```

If I connect the drive to a rear USB port everything seems to work as expected (although not at rocket speed).

Other info:

- The two PCs have different motherboards: Asus ROG Max V Gene and Asrock H87M Pro4
- The external drive is not damaged
- It works on Windows (both on front and back ports)
- The drive is a Samsung M3 Portable 1TB model HX-M101TCB/G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be related to some settings in the BIOS.

Under the UEFI bios of both motherboards there's an USB section with many options, I played a bit with them and it turned out that "USB Legacy" (for USB 2.0 only) must be disabled for the front panel USB to work.

Strangely enough all other USB ports (back panel) work correctly despite that setting.